# Reading SMS user settings for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sms

I wish to access whether or not the user lets his/her iPhone preview the contents of incoming SMS messages. This toggle is found in Settings > Messages > Show Preview. Is there a way to access (read only) this information legit (I need to get the app approved)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's sandboxed along with the other core phone functionality.